# Adding "fields" to an Interface in Golang

Tags: go

I have a 'class' CustomClient that does some HTTP operations and holds some data in a custom struct.
One of the members of CustomClient is the Golang http.Client

```
type CustomClient struct {
    commData                        CustomDataStruct
    httpClient                      *http.Client
}
```

I am trying to add some extra "testability" to CustomClient. Currently, I cannot control the type of HTTP responses that httpClient responds with. **CustomClient** only uses httpClient to run **httpClient.Do()**, so I had an idea to create an "Interface" to implement this method, so I wanted to make it like:

```
type Client interface {
    Do(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error)
}

type CustomClient struct {
    commData                        CustomDataStruct
    httpClient                      Client
}
```

Then I created my own class **HttpClientMOCK** with a Do() method that will return some custom response for testing purposes:

```
type HttpClientMOCK struct {
    Transport *http.Transport
}

func NewHttpClientMOCK() *HttpClientMOCK {
    c := &HttpClientMOCK{
        Transport: &http.Transport{},
    }
    return c
}

func (c *HttpClientMOCK) Do(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

**There is just one problem** - One of the "member functions" of CustomClient manually assigns http.Client.Transport, which is used by the original http.Client. The line looks like this:

```
func (cc *CustomClient) updateClient() {
    transport := ... // Do some operations
    cc.httpClient.Transport = transport
}
```

The above line gives the error - *Unresolved reference 'Transport'*

So I guess Golang has no way of knowing that both http.Client and HttpClientMOCK actually have this member **Transport** because my Interface **Client** only specifies one method.

Is there any workaround to this issue? AFAIK my hands are tied here because there is no way to define a "data field" for an interface.

Comment: Ugh, replacing a `Transport` in an existing `http.Client` is a bad idea. Might want to refactor that part. Also the [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http) say: "*Clients and Transports are safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines and for efficiency should only be created once and re-used.*"

Comment: But I wouldnt be replace a Transport in an EXISTING http.Client, Im trying to pass MY OWN custom http.Client. Thats the whole point here, being able to pass my own httpClient without changing the original operation of the existing httpClient

Comment: If it's only set at initialization, it should be set at creation time (which requires a value of a concrete type anyway), not at some later point by a member function of a different type.

Answer (score 0):

The abstraction of an HTTP client with the method `Do` is very nice but later in the code, changing the transport breaks that abstraction. That should be reviewed, is there any limitating reason to do that? (for example using multiple client side certs to authenticate requests)

To get the code working, it is always possible casting to `*http.Client`:

```golang
func (cc *CustomClient) updateClient() {
    if h, ok := cc.httpClient.(*http.Client); ok {
        transport := ... // Do some operations
        h.Transport = transport
    }
}
```